# How to get all hardlinks to the same data?

Tags: freebsd, hardlink

Have several hardlinks to the same file.
How (for example) by one file(hardlink) get others pointing to the same data?
*No real task. Just interesting. May be useful.*

Comment: The question is the answer.  What did you _actually_ mean to ask?  How to create hard links?  [What hard links are and how they work?](http://superuser.com/questions/299498/)  [What are hard links used for?](http://superuser.com/questions/288286/)  Lots of these questions have already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most filesystems do not maintain a directory of where the hardlinks to a file (or more precisely, to an indode) are.

So you'll have to scan the whole filesystem to find all hardlinks. You can do this using `find -inum <inode number>`.

Example:

Create file with link:

```
$ ~> mkdir linktest
$ ~> cd linktest/
$ ~/linktest> touch file1
$ ~/linktest> ln file1 file2
```

Check inodes:

```
$ ~/linktest> stat file*
  File: file1
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 805h/2053d      Inode: 37          Links: 2
[...]
  File: file2
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 805h/2053d      Inode: 37          Links: 2
[...]
```

As you can see, both file entries have the same inode (37) - because they are hardlinks to the same data.

Find by inode number:

```
$ ~/linktest> find -inum 37
./file1
./file2
```

This is on Linux, but it should work the same on *BSD.

Comment: what filesystems can do it without scanning every file?

Comment: @Sergey: No idea. I don't know any.

Answer (score 2):

`find` has an option `-samefile` for this:

```
find / -xdev -samefile /myfile
```

Replace `/` with the root of the filesystem that `myfile` is on – for example, if you used `/home/sergey/myfile` and you have `/home` on a separate filesystem, then use `find /home`.